# Command to rebuild all DKMS modules for all installed kernels?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, dkms

Occasionally, my system gets into a state where some kernels are missing a module or two, because DKMS somehow forgot to compile those modules for that kernel. Rather than spend time diagnosing the problem, it would be nice if there was a single command I could run that woudl just rebuild *every* dkms-controlled module for *every* installed kernel. Is there such a command?

Comment: I always get the output Module broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112 already installed on kernel 2.6.38jon-64/x86_64 I really want a --force or a --rebuild --just-do-what-i-say option ;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I figured out a shell one-liner to do it:

```
ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools | \
    sudo xargs -n1 /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start
```

This works because the names of the directories in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools` are exactly the kernel version names that you need to pass to `dkms_autoinstaller` to tell it to rebuild all modules for those kernel versions. Note that if you have uninstalled some old kernels, their directories might still be lying around and cause some errors to be reported, but this isn't a problem because `dkms_autoinstaller` will just do nothing for those kernel versions that aren't installed.

Comment: it gave some errors because it came up headers-xxx and headers-xxx-generic but it seemed to rebuild the correct stuff despite the errors

Comment: @frankster After finding multiple "Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file." for a new kernel installation, I was able to install previous kernel modules listed by `dkms status` to the new kernel using the following per specific modules I wanted from "/usr/src" .  Parameters need to be changed as needed for -c, -m, -v . Here is an example for the nvidia-384-384.90 module:  
`ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools | \  
sudo xargs -n1 /usr/sbin/dkms install -c /usr/src/nvidia-384-384.90/dkms.conf -m nvidia -v 384-384.90 -k `

Comment: `/var/lib/initramfs-tools` is **no more populated** for `LTS 22.04` nor Debian `bullseye` (directory is missing)

Comment: `/usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start` worked after booting into the kernel I needed to build for.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't look like the `dkms` command allows you to do that. I created a small Python script that should do what you want. You can put an alias in your `~/.bashrc` like

```
alias dkms-buildall='sudo ./wherever/your/script/is'
```

Of course you'd need to make it executable first. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/env python
#
# NOTE: This assumes that all modules and versions are built for at
#       least one kernel. If that's not the case, adapt parsing as needed.
import os
import subprocess

# Permission check.
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    print "You need to be root to run this script."
    exit(1)

# Get DKMS status output.
cmd = ['dkms', 'status']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
dkms_status = process.communicate()[0].strip('\n').split('\n')
dkms_status = [x.split(', ') for x in dkms_status]

# Get kernel versions (probably crap).
cmd = ['ls', '/var/lib/initramfs-tools/']
# Alternative (for use with Arch Linux for example)
# cmd = ['ls', '/usr/lib/modules/']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
kernels = process.communicate()[0].strip('\n').split('\n')

# Parse output, 'modules' will contain all modules pointing to a set
# of versions.
modules = {}

for entry in dkms_status:
   module = entry[0]
   version = entry[1].split(': ')[0]
   try:
      modules[module].add(version)
   except KeyError:
      # We don't have that module, add it.
      modules[module] = set([version])

# For each module, build all versions for all kernels.
for module in modules:
   for version in modules[module]:
      for kernel in kernels:
         cmd = ['dkms', 'build', '-m', module, '-v', version, '-k', kernel]
         ret = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Tested it here, seems to work just fine:

```
$ dkms status
nvidia-current, 275.09.07, 3.0.0-5-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.0.10, 3.0.0-5-generic, x86_64: installed

$ sudo python dkms.py
...

$ dkms status
nvidia-current, 275.09.07, 3.0.0-5-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-current, 275.09.07, 3.0-2-generic, x86_64: built
nvidia-current, 275.09.07, 3.0-3-generic, x86_64: built
virtualbox, 4.0.10, 3.0.0-5-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.0.10, 3.0-2-generic, x86_64: built
virtualbox, 4.0.10, 3.0-3-generic, x86_64: built
```

If you also want to install the modules, replace *build* with *install* in the second last line.

Answer (score 6):

Combining @htorque and @Ryan Thompson's answers, here's my (as root) one-liner:

```
dkms status | sed s/,//g | awk '{print "-m",$1,"-v",$2}' | while read line; do ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools | xargs -n 1 dkms install $line -k; done
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't have enough reputation to comment `@Ryan Thompson`'s answer, but this might be useful to somebody. In Ubuntu 22.04 there's no `/var/lib/initramfs-tools` directory, however, there're `initrd.img-<kernel version>` images present in `/boot` per every installed kernel version, and these `<kernel version>` are exactly what `dkms` (and `dkms_autoinstaller`) needs. So let's use them:

```
ls /boot/initrd.img-* | cut -d- -f2- | \
    sudo xargs -n1 /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start
```

Answer (score 4):

An edit of script by @htorque. Use it in case you want a **force**rebuild (and install) of already built modules. Switched to python3, `subprocess.run()` requires Python 3.5+.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# NOTE: This assumes that all modules and versions are built for at
#       least one kernel. If that's not the case, adapt parsing as needed.
import os
import subprocess
import re

# Permission check.
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    print("You need to be root to run this script.")
    exit(1)

# Get DKMS status output.
cmd = ['dkms', 'status']
dkms_status = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8").strip('\n').split('\n')
dkms_status = [re.split(', |/', x) for x in dkms_status]

##
# Get kernel versions (probably crap).
#cmd = ['ls', '/var/lib/initramfs-tools/']  # Does not work on Ubuntu 22.04
# Alternative (for use with Arch Linux for example)
# cmd = ['ls', '/usr/lib/modules/']
#kernels = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8").strip('\n').split('\n')
##

## Works on 22.04
prefix = 'initrd.img-'
kernels = [k[len(prefix):] for k in os.listdir('/boot')
           if k.startswith(prefix)]
##

# Parse output, 'modules' will contain all modules pointing to a set
# of versions.
modules = {}

for entry in dkms_status:
   module = entry[0]
   version = entry[1].split(': ')[0]
   try:
      modules[module].add(version)
   except KeyError:
      # We don't have that module, add it.
      modules[module] = set([version])

# For each module, build all versions for all kernels.
for module in modules:
   for version in modules[module]:
      for kernel in kernels:
         for action in ['remove', 'install']:
            cmd = ['dkms', action, '-m', module, '-v', version, '-k', kernel]
            subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

The above don't work on all variants, this might be a bit more helpful in those cases...

```
$modulename="whatever"
$moduleversion=`modinfo $modulename | grep "^version:" | awk '{ print $2 }'`
dkms status | grep $modulename | tr -d ',' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -n1 dkms build $modulename/$moduleversion -k
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this does that the other methods don't?

Comment: It works on systems that don't have /usr/src/linux-headers-* and  /var/lib/initramfs-tools

Comment: consider the situation where you need it to run on many various linux distros that only have the fact that dkms (sort of) works, in common.

Answer (score 0):

`dkms status` and `dkms_autoinstaller` does not work in ubuntu 16.x. So some shell script will do.
This script assumed you have proper `*-dkms` deb-package installed, and `bash` is your shell.

```
for k in $(ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools) ; do
 for d in $(cd /usr/src; ls -d *-*) ; do
  [[ -f /usr/src/${d}/dkms.conf ]] || continue
  m=$(echo $d | sed -r -e 's/-([0-9]).+//')
  v=$(echo $d | sed -r -e 's/[^0-9]+-([0-9])/\1/')
  sudo /usr/sbin/dkms install -c /usr/src/$d/dkms.conf -m $m -v $v -k $k
 done
done
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also simply invoke update-initramfs -u and it will do it for you.

Comment: `update-initramfs -u` only does it for one kernel, not "all installed kernels" as the question asks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1342133)