# Kernel upgrade breaks Asus USB-N13 WiFi card Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server, kernel, dkms

I compiled and installed USB-N13 wifi drivers using dkms. Everything was fine with the WiFi and I also had 1 successful kernel upgrade(3.2.0-24). Since kernel version 3.2.0-25 (and recently 3.2.0-26) my wifi card can't connect to my AP.

iwconfig output is below:

```
ra0   Ralink STA  ESSID:"11n-AP"  Nickname:"RT2870STA"
      Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
      Bit Rate:1 Mb/s
      RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

my /etc/network/interfaces file is below:

```
#WiFi network Card
auto ra0
iface ra0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <myNetrowk>
wpa-psk <myPassword>
```

**Update 1**:
I totally forgot to mention that after I reboot system 4-5 times Wifi starts to work again. Would like to know where should I start to look for the issues since this behavior is not acceptable.

Comment: This will help http://askubuntu.com/a/53428/63025

Comment: @tijybba: Thank you for the information. The module gets created and it looks like it is the same as if I do a fresh wifi install for the current version of kernel

Comment: Also consider the following detailed  answer by izx if such problem further persists in future kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to rebuild the driver module for your card. Here's how:

- Your adapter has a Ralink RT2870 chipset. You can download the official Linux drivers from [this site](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5021). Save them to your Downloads folder (default):

  [image]
- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and paste the following, line by line:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
  cd Downloads
  tar -xaf 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1.tar.bz2
  cd 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1
  WPA1=HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT
  WPA2=HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT
  sed -i -e "s/$WPA1=n/$WPA1=y/g" -e "s/$WPA2=n/$WPA2=y/g" os/linux/config.mk
  sudo make && sudo make install && sudo make clean
  cd ..
  ```
- Reboot, and hopefully your wireless connection will work!
- Then open up the Downloads folder in the File Manager and delete the downloaded Ralink file/folder.

  [image]

Comment: I'm using server/noGUI. But thanks for this!