# Ubuntu 20.04 issues with TP Link AC1300 Archer T4U

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, tp-link

I think this worked on the previous Linux versions, but with the new version, the dongle just doesn't get recognized. From the drivers offered on TP-Link's page, there is a Linux installation guide which doesn't seem to be working.

Anyone has any ideas if there's a way I can make this work? I have the feeling it has something to do with the new kernel...

Comment: If it is `rtl8812au` you can try `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms` from the official repos.

Comment: I feel like I am doing something wrong. I got these installed. Now I see the dongle is actually recognized and the WiFi option appears. However, it doesn't have its usual light indicator, and it doesn't find any networks. I have another nameless brand from AliExpress - same issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several different hardware revisions, so first you'll need to figure out which one you have. There are a couple different methods:

- Look at the the device

  - Either on the label of the device or on the metal where it plugs in should be the `FCC-ID`. The version is at the end of this value starting with `V`, for example `TE7T4UV32` is v3.2

    For more information, see here: https://www.tp-link.com/support/faq/46/
- Match the device ID

  - Plug the device in, and run this command: `lsusb`. You should see an entry like this one:

    `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC`

    The hardware ID should tell you which version you have:

    - `2357:0101`: v1
    - `2357:010d`: v2
    - `2357:0115`: v3

Now you can install the driver depending which hardware version you have:

### v1 and v2

These devices have the `rtl8812au` chipset and you should be able to do as [Pilot6 suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230788/ubuntu-20-04-issues-with-tp-link-ac1300-archer-t4u#comment2071641_1230788):

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

### v3

This device has the `rtl8812bu` chipset and you'll need to do a little more work to get it working. Thankfully there's a working driver available for it here: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

To get it working, you'll need to first install some packages and check out the Git repo:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
```

Then follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu#dkms-installation) to install the driver:

```
cd rtl88x2bu
./deploy.sh
```

**Note:** I previously recommended [the driver suggested by Diego](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274821/18665) (https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu), but I can no longer recommend that driver:

- After resuming from suspend, it would no longer connect to wireless networks and I would have to unplug and replug the device
- That driver is a fork of a fork and unfortunately there is no way to report issues

##### Upgrade v3 driver

If you've previously installed the kernel driver for the v3 device and need to upgrade it:

1. Update the git repository

   - If you already have it checked out: `git pull`
   - Otherwise, re-clone it (see above)
2. Run the deploy script again

   ```
   ./deploy.sh
   ```

   If you get an error, you may need to remove the driver first:

   ```
   sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1 --all
   ```
3. Install the driver for all other kernels (the deploy script only installs it for the current kernel)

   ```
   ls /boot/initrd.img-* | cut -d- -f2- | \
       sudo xargs -n1 /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start
   ```

   (Source: [Command to rebuild all DKMS modules for all installed kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412716/18665))

Answer (score 4):

Only the `bu` https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu driver worked for me on kernel 5.4.0-7642-generic. The driver TPLink provides here https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t4u/#Driver is not compatible with newer Kernels.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/blob/v5.6.4.2/README.md

Test this driver, works perfectly in 20.04.

Comment: Now the dongle is somewhat recognized, but doesn't have its light on and it doesn't find any networks.

Comment: @SvetoslavAntonov same problem here... have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. It seems I had to install this driver - rtl8812bu (https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu) and it worked after that. No idea why I had to install this for linux, while for Windows the "au" driver works.

Answer (score 0):

Since this topic is one of the first ones on google search for the problem, I'd like to add that the driver suggested in this topic does no seems to work on 5.11 kernel (currently in 21.04 and 21.10)

But the driver from GITHub [Linux Driver for USB WiFi Adapters that are based on the RTL8812BU and RTL8822BU Chipsets](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu) appears to work just fine.

Comment: I'm using the driver recommended in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298491/18665) for the v3 device right now with the 5.11 kernel. It might be helpful to be more specific as to which device you're using and which driver doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

My TP-Link AC600 - Archer T2U Plus ver 1.0
ID: **2357**:**0120**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
```

works with rtl8814au driver (on Ubuntu 20.04 Server)

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
sudo make dkms_install
iwconfig
```

Comment: The OP explains in a comment that the `rtl8814au` driver does not work for them and they needed the `bu` alternate ...

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13 for me it works with driver from https://www.cudytech.com/wu1200_software_download