# Archer T4U AC1300 not working

Tags: networking, usb

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-27-generic. Relevant line of lsusb: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:010d TP-Link 802.11n NIC`

As in [Ubuntu 20.04 issues with TP Link AC1300 Archer T4U](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230788/ubuntu-20-04-issues-with-tp-link-ac1300-archer-t4u), I installed `rtl8812au-dkms` package, but wireless internet still doesn't work.
Running `ifconfig` shows no `wlan0` interface:

```
enp31s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::df3b:e203:f56d:4363  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:17:a4:99:88:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 182194  bytes 273796743 (273.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93172  bytes 6781999 (6.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 257  bytes 25594 (25.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 257  bytes 25594 (25.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm not sure what to do to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of *rtl8812au-dkms* in the Ubuntu repositories doesn't cover your exact device. I suggest that you do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential bc
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Unplug and replug the device. You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now.